# page break by length and group sas proc report

Tags: sas

I would like to create a page break value that can help me break the page when I use proc report.

Now my data looks like this:

Group Value

a     1

a     2

a     3

...

b     1

b     2

...

c     1

c     2

c     3

And suppose I only want **two lines** per page, and break if the group changed.
So I need a dataset like this:

Group Value Page

a     1      1

a     2      1

a     3      2

...

b     1      3

b     2      3

...

c     1      4

c     2      4

c     3      5

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need the MOD() function, along with `_n_` and some by group processing. Please show anything you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Retain holds values across rows. Create a counter value that you can use to track the number of records per group. This allows you to split it into pages of N amount.
- Use BY and FIRST to reset counter at the start of each group
- Check if the you need to increment page

```
data have;
input Group $ Value;
cards;
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
c 3
;;;;

data want;
set have;
by group;

retain counter page;

if first.group then counter=0;

counter+1;

if mod(counter, 2) =1 or first.group then page+1;

run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs Group   Value   counter page
1   a   1   1   1
2   a   2   2   1
3   a   3   3   2
4   b   1   1   3
5   b   2   2   3
6   c   1   1   4
7   c   2   2   4
8   c   3   3   5
```